# Stop .click() command running once system printer popup window opens

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, click

Working on web scraping since approximately 2 hours, I am using python selenium webdriver in order to extract a plain text table.

The webpage I am working on displays a dynamic table with the first 10 entries. Next to the table there is a print button that, once clicked, opens a new window with all the table entries in plain text (that's what I try to get).

The problem is that there is also the mac print popup window that also opens, waiting for pressing the cancel button before I can actually interact with the plain text table window.

When running the commands below, the last command `print_button.click()` keeps running in my terminal until I press the cancel button in the printer popup window.

I saw a couple of potential solutions to programmatically press the cancel print button (using `ActionChains` commands for instance), but I would first need to stop my `print_button.click()` running.

How could I make the `print_button.click()` command to stop once the printer window opens?
Or maybe prevent firefox to open any system print windows?

Pseudo-code:

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

driver.get('my_URL')

print_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/my_element/span")

# this is the command that keeps running until I click the cancel print button
print_button.click()
```

Comment: Not sure why you are clicking on the print button if you don't want to print the content.

Comment: why do you think it "keeps running"?  I think what you need here is unexpected prompt behavior, but it can be problematic if the call is onpageload.  Include the markup of the page that calls "window.print()" along with event handler.